# Using "assumes" in a sentence

Tags: semantics

Are the sentences

> This formula assumes standardised features.
>
> This formula uses standardised features.

semantically equivalent to

> This formula assumes that all features have been standardised.

?

Comment: The first is. The second isn't. The first suggests the formula relies on standardised features, perhaps to guarantee the accuracy of its results. The second suggests the formula directly incorporates these standardised features.

Comment: I agree with you.The second seemed to me like it was different really. I'll use the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "semantically equivalent to" we mean "roughly the same as", then yes. Although to me, the 3rd one (This formula assumes that all features have been standardised) sounds like a disclaimer, hence rather unsure of itself (= it wasn't me!), which doesn't inspire trust.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant. I agree with you on the third sentence. I wanted to use the first one, but I wasn't sure it would be received the same way. Thank you for the answer :)